# Change database value

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I want to change some value in my database, pressing on picture on my page, using javascript and AJAX. How can I do it?

Comment: By writing some code. By chance, do you have any already?

Comment: What do you expect someone to answer with? This is way too broad of a question.

Comment: This question is overly broad. What's the problem? Changing data in a database? Making an HTTP request with Ajax? Binding a function to a click on an image?

Comment: problem with 'Making an HTTP request with Ajax'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use xmlhttprequest, and the javascript :

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // Create new XHR
var url = 'http://sample.com/change.php'; // The url
var data = 'data=sample&back=come';
xhr.open('POST', url, true); // POST is method you can with `POST|GET`
xhr.send(data);
```

or it can be simplifer with jquery

```
var url = 'http://sample.com/change.php'; // The url
var data = 'data=sample&back=come';
$.post(url,data,function(callback){
  alert(callback);
});
```

and sure bind it on your image:

```
$("img").click(function(){
    var url = 'http://sample.com/change.php'; // The url
    var data = 'data=sample&back=come';
    $.post(url,data,function(callback){
     alert(callback);
    });
});
```

then the php file:

```
<?php
$post_data = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['data']);
$post_back = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['back']);
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE table SET data = '".$post_data."' WHERE `back` = '".$post_back."'"); // This is a query, change it with yours
if($query){echo'Success';} //Print a success message
?>
```

Finish, good luck

Comment: excluding outdated `mysql_*` functions, the above code will throw parse error.

Comment: `Print a success message`.... see above.

Comment: sorry i wrong, check it again !